# Outlet in a Static Table Cell Causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS on load

Tags: xcode, uitableview, iboutlet

I am creating a simple Static Table with 2 sections, 2 Cells in each section. the Table View controller (TVC) is `Subclassed`.

Within each of the table cells I have a stepper Control, and and a label. I am using this to allow for updating though an `IBAction` from the Stepper, setting a property in the TVC. At the same time the label is updated through it's outlet to show the current value.

The outlet is defined in the @interface section of the "TVC.m" file as is normal using the standard IB tools.

On run it breaks on the Thread 1 level `under UIApplicationMain` in something named _0 obj_loadWeakRetained_ and the error is:

> THREAD 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code -2, address = 0x1da7cc0.

Any idea what I may be doing incorrectly? is there something that has to be done differently when adding views to `tablecells` and setting outlets to them?
Here's the code  - nothing unusual.

```
#import "AdvancedTVC.h"

@interface AdvancedTVC ()

- (IBAction)stepperChanged:(UIStepper *)sender;
- (IBAction)switchToggled:(UISwitch *)sender;


@end

@implementation AdvancedTVC

- (IBAction)stepperChanged:(UIStepper *)sender {
}
- (IBAction)switchToggled:(UISwitch *)sender {
}



- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}

@end
```

Comment: Could you include your code for the @interface section of the "TVC.m"?

Comment: I ended up redoing the entire view differently. Thanks for helping. Not enough time to figure out the issue. It may be somehting that I was doing so fundamentally wrong that I couldn't articulate it. the don't know what you don't know syndrome.